# How does accessing class level variables in java work?

Tags: java, class, syntax, variables, static

I'm doing my third online course in learning java because I couldn't get over how to even start a project from scratch. There was a lesson in this new course that made me ask this question of the code and how to write it. It was verses using the dot notation when using class level variables.

This is how the instructor's code looked:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TicTacT {

    public static String usrStr;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.print("Enter some text: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        TicTacT.usrStr = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println(TicTacT.usrStr);

    }

}
```

Now here is my version of the same code which worked too.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TicTacT {

    public static String usrStr;
    public static String instruction = "Enter some text: ";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.print(instruction);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        usrStr = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println(usrStr);

    }
}
```

So are both ways of accessing class level variables correct and it is just personal preference?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/16880338: *"Static variables are shared [class] variables. You can access them using either the Classname.staticVariable or using an object of the class instance.staticVariable. In any case you will be referring to the single copy of the variable in memory, no matter how many objects you create."*

Comment: When you say `usrStr = input.nextLine();` you are accessing the variable using the `instance.staticVariable` form.  `instance` is implied.  Java allows this; in the C# language, only the `TicTacT.usrStr = input.nextLine();` form is allowed, and I believe that is the only form you should use to access a static variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `Classname.fieldname` makes it clear to a reader that fieldname is a **static** field.

Using `anInstanceOfTheClass.fieldname` (or the implicit form as pointed out by @Robert Harvey) leaves the reader guessing, in fact, most would mistakenly assume that fieldname is an instance variable.

I prefer clarity and readibility.